# How to Validate FormArray length in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a data driven form in angular2 like below

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  'name': ['',Validators.required],
  'description': ['', Validators.required],
  'places': this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.minlength(1)) 
})
```

I want to add validations to the `place` formArray, so i am adding `minlength` validation, but minlength validation is not working on formArray.

What are the other validations for formArray, so that form must be valid only when places array contain atleast one place.

Comment: Scratch that is should work https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/7383e4a8012962430e8925b57554089cf92173cc

Comment: You may also be interested in this https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/17c5fa9293bbfc30625c139caccad15ee883a0e3 anyway this should work make sure you have an up-to-date version

Answer (score 65):

`Validators.required` does the magic for you:

```js
// using required 

this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    taskTreeId: [Common.UID()],
    executionProgrammedTime: ["", [Validators.required]],
    description: [""],
    tasks: this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.required)
});  

// using custom validation

export const minLengthArray = (min: number) => {
  return (c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    if (c.value.length >= min)
      return null;

    return { MinLengthArray: true};
  }
}

 this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        taskTreeId: [Common.UID()],
        executionProgrammedTime: ["", [Validators.required]],
        description: [""],
        tasks: this.formBuilder.array([], minLengthArray(2))
    });
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded" 
    [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">SAVE</button>
```

Comment: hello, i implemented this but it does not work. i am unable to change the form.valid to 'true' eventhough i have a checkbox ticked. anything else i need to add?

Comment: You can also use Validators.maxLength or minLength if you want to constraint the length of your array in some other way.

Comment: This is the correct answer, `Validators.required` calls function named `isEmptyInputValue` which check if value is `null` or `length === 0`.

See [Angular Source file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L199)

Comment: @NetanelDraiman thanks a lot for the insight! I wanted to be extra sure of how `required` form array validation is done in angular.

Comment: Hard to believe Angular doesn't provide this very basic checking right out of the box

Answer (score 35):

Add this custom validator to your validation service:

```
minLengthArray(min: number) {
    return (c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        if (c.value.length >= min)
            return null;

        return { 'minLengthArray': {valid: false }};
    }
}
```

And then when creating the form do the following:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  'name': ['',Validators.required],
  'description': ['', Validators.required],
  'places': this.formBuilder.array([], this.validationService.minLengthArray(1)) 
});
```

And you can check errors against the `FormArray` by checking `FormArray.hasError('minLengthArray')`

Comment: Hey, it actually works : ) - But how do I make it "bubble up" to the form -
 preventing submit (it doesn't for me) ?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?  Here is an example: <div [ngClass]="['form-group', !form.controls.files.valid ? 'has-danger' : 'has-success']">
                            <file-upload (filesChanged)="onFilesChanged($event)" [allowReplace]="true" [files]="data.files"></file-upload>
                            <div class="form-control-feedback" *ngIf="!form.controls.files.valid">Must upload file to create order</div>
                        </div> And I have this in my ts: this.form = this._fb.group({
                files: this._fb.array([], this._vs.minLengthArray(1))
            });

Comment: OK that would work, but I was hoping for a way to make this custom validator, automagically, "influence" the forms (in)validity, so I don't have to check the formArrays validity explicitly - just like with the built-in Validators..  And now, it seems, it does exactly that - don't know why it didn't yesterday :D

Comment: for TypeScript null safety, make it `if (c.value?.length >= min)`

Answer (score 8):

because you using wrong validator function name: `minlength` -> `minLength`

demo code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="tpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div><input type="text" formControlName="name"></div>
      <div><textarea formControlName="description"></textarea></div>
      <div formArrayName="places">
        <button type="button" (click)="addPlace()">+</button>
        <div *ngFor="let place of places.controls; let i = index">
          <div>
              <span>Places {{i + 1}}</span>
              <button type="button" *ngIf="places.controls.length > 0" 
                  (click)="removePlace(i)">
                  x
              </button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <p>Status: {{ tpForm.valid }}</p>
  `,
  styles: [
    `


    `
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  tpForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tpForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': ['',Validators.required],
      'description': ['', Validators.required],
      'places': this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ], Validators.minLength(1))
    })
  }

  get places(): FormArray {
    return this.tpForm.get('places') as FormArray;
  }

  onSubmit() {

  }

  addPlace() {
    this.places.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }

  removePlace(index) {
    this.places.removeAt(index);
  }

}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/cfi7nN?p=preview

Answer (score 7):

**Good and clear way to do this is :**

Create a `Array.validator.ts` and put all the custom validations over there , like `minLength` , `maxLength` etc

```
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

// Array Validators
export class ArrayValidators {

    // max length
    public static maxLength(max: number): ValidatorFn | any {
        return (control: AbstractControl[]) => {
            if (!(control instanceof FormArray)) return;
            return control.length > max ? { maxLength: true } : null;
        }
    }

    // min length
    public static minLength(min: number): ValidatorFn | any {
        return (control: AbstractControl[]) => {
            if (!(control instanceof FormArray)) return;
            return control.length < min ? { minLength: true } : null;
        }
    }
}
```

And Then just import that file and use validation wherever you want to :

```
import { ArrayValidators } from './array.validator'; // Import it

'hobbies':new FormArray([],ArrayValidators.minLength(2)) // Use it
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-array-length)**

---

> Note :
>
> You can directly use this package also **[ng-validator](https://github.com/Lugriz/ng-validator)** ( Reference is taken from this package ) , But If
>   you need just required array validations you can do it like above.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you. I was trying to use the standard `Validators.minLength(1)` to no avail. Somehow I assumed that internally, `SOME_OBJECT.length` or `SOME_STRING.length` would be able to use the same validator...

Answer (score 5):

if you are trying to add validation to formarray try this may help you,

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  'name': ['',Validators.required],
  'description': ['', Validators.required],
  'places': this.formBuilder.array(this.initPlaces()) 
})

initPlaces() {       
        return this._fb.group({
            places: ['',[Validators.minLength(1)]]           
        });
  }
```

this `initPlaces` will simply return formGroup with validation as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Having a template

```
<div formArrayName="items">
    <div *ngFor="[...] let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">

    [...]

    </div>
</div>
```

You could simply use this in your button :

```
[disabled]="!myForm.get('items.1')"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [''],
      lastName: [''],
      hobbies: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')], Validators.minLength(2))
});
```

Just use the `Validators.minLength(length)`.
https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#minLength