# Angular Reactive Form manual validate gives ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular 5.0.0 and Material 5.2.2.

This form has two sub questions in it. The user is submitting two times in one form. This has to stay this way because I present here a very stripped down version of my original form.

After the first submit, in the second subquestion, I validate if there is minimum one checked checkbox. If not I do an `this.choicesSecond.setErrors({'incorrect': true});`. This 
disables the `submit` button in a correct way. But this gives an error:

> `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

I think it has to do with with `change detection`. If I do an extra change detection with `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` then the error disappears but the submit button is not disabled anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Template:

```
<mat-card>
    <form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" novalidate>
        <div *ngIf="!subQuestion">
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>
                    <h3>Which fruit do you like most?</h3>
                </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
                <mat-radio-group formControlName="choiceFirst">
                    <div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits; let i=index" class="space">
                        <mat-radio-button [value]="fruit">{{fruit}}</mat-radio-button>
                    </div>
                </mat-radio-group>
            </mat-card-content>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="subQuestion">
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>
                    <h3>Whichs fruits do you like?</h3>
                </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
                <div *ngFor="let choiceSecond of choicesSecond.controls; let i=index">
                    <mat-checkbox [formControl]="choiceSecond">{{fruits[i]}}</mat-checkbox>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
        </div>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </form>
</mat-card>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {

  myForm: FormGroup;
  fruits: Array<string> = ["apple", "pear", "kiwi", "banana", "grape", "strawberry", "grapefruit", "melon", "mango", "plum"];
  numChecked: number = 0;
  subQuestion: boolean = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'choiceFirst': [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
    let choicesFormArray = this.fruits.map(fruit => { return this.formBuilder.control(false) });
    this.myForm.setControl('choicesSecond', this.formBuilder.array(choicesFormArray));
    this.onChangeAnswers();
  }

  onChangeAnswers() {
    this.choicesSecond.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      let numChecked = value.filter(item => item).length;
      if (numChecked === 0 ) this.choicesSecond.setErrors({'incorrect': true});
    });
  }

  get choicesSecond(): FormArray {
    return this.myForm.get('choicesSecond') as FormArray;
  };

  onSubmit(submit) {
    if (!this.subQuestion) {
      this.subQuestion = true;
      let numChecked = this.choicesSecond.controls.filter(item => item.value).length;
      if (numChecked === 0 ) this.choicesSecond.setErrors({'incorrect': true});
      // this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
    }
    console.log(submit);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues comes from the `this.choicesSecond.setErrors({'incorrect': true});`, when you click submit you create the component and at the same time change its value. This fails in development mode because of the aditional check done by angular. [Here is a good article about this error.](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

For form validation you can use a custom validator, [an example in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44574867/8945135) :

```
minLengthArray(min: number) {
    return (c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        if (c.value.length >= min)
            return null;

        return { 'minLengthArray': {valid: false }};
    }
}
```

And for steps, as you are using angular material you could use the [mat-stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).

Comment: Here is a fork of the angular stepper demo with your code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50134925

Comment: In your stepper example in step 1 the `Validators.required` doesn't work. In step 2 nothing is visible. Also you use two forms, that should be one form. But I see in de mat-stepper documentation that is supported as well. Thanks, I really appreciate the effort you take to help me. I think the mat-stepper can help me to give a better UI/UX for the user. But I do not think it's the solution to my problem. But if we solve the original problem we can implement this solution into the mat-stepper. Do you have any idea why stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-question-50134925-try-1 is not working?

Comment: The validator condition must be : `if (c.value.filter(_=>_).length >= min)`

Comment: I wouldn't use the same button for next and submit. And initialise my form with validators.

Comment: I don't see how that will solve the problem. I think this will shift the problem.

Comment: It avoids changing the value in the wrong moment in the verification lifecycle, here is and edit : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50134925-2

Comment: In phase 2 submit button works now. But that shifts the problem to the `next` button in phase 1. This button is not disabled anymore when nothing is selected.

Comment: Just needs to add `[disabled]="myForm.get('choiceFirst').invalid"` for the next button : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50134925-2

Comment: Can you explain why you need the `.filter(_=>_)` in the validator condition? Seems like a way to clone the array?

Comment: The control value is an array of booleans. Its just a compact version of `.filter(value => value === true)` to get the subarray of selected values.

Comment: The solution with only one submit button also works now. I forgot to add `this.myForm.get('choicesSecond').updateValueAndValidity();`

Comment: But I agree that your two button solution is a better one and also needed if I want to implement the mat-stepper. Thanks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution @ibenjelloun works well with two adjustments (see also comments under his solution):

1. `if (c.value.length >= min)` needs to be `if (c.value.filter(item => item).length >= min)` filtering only the checkboxes that are checked.
2. the setControl of 'choicesSecond' needs to be done after the first submit in `onSubmit` method and not the `ngOnInit` hook. Here also you need to do the `setValidators` and `updateValueAndValidity`.

As @ibenjelloun suggested the solution is better with an extra button going from first subquestion to the second subquestion because implementing a `back` button is only possible this way.

Here is the final component that works:

```
export class AppComponent {

  myForm: FormGroup;
  fruits: Array<string> = ["apple", "pear", "kiwi", "banana", "grape", "strawberry", "grapefruit", "melon", "mango", "plum"];
  subQuestion: boolean = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'choiceFirst': [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  minLengthArray(min: number) {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      if (c.value.filter(item => item).length >= min)
        return null;
      return { 'minLengthArray': { valid: false } };
    }
  }

  get choicesSecond(): FormArray {
    return this.myForm.get('choicesSecond') as FormArray;
  };

  onSubmit(submit) {
    if (!this.subQuestion) {
      let choicesSecondFormArray = this.fruits.map(fruit => { return this.formBuilder.control(false) });
      this.myForm.setControl('choicesSecond', this.formBuilder.array(choicesSecondFormArray));
      this.myForm.get('choicesSecond').setValidators(this.minLengthArray(1));
      this.myForm.get('choicesSecond').updateValueAndValidity();
      this.subQuestion = true;
    }
    console.log(submit);
  }

}
```